# Uvicorn reload options are not being followed

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

I have three directories: app, config, and private

I'm running uvicorn programmatically like this with WatchFiles installed:

```py
uvicorn.run(
        "app.main:fast",
        host=host,
        port=port,
        log_level=log_level,
        reload=reload,
        reload_includes=["app/*", "config/*", "manage.py", ".env"],
    )
```

But for some reason, the directory private is also watched and reloads. I tried doing this:

```py
uvicorn.run(
        "app.main:fast",
        host=host,
        port=port,
        log_level=log_level,
        reload=reload,
        reload_dirs=["app", "config"],
        reload_includes=["app/*.py", "config/*.py", "manage.py", ".env"],
        reload_excludes=["*.py"]
    )
```

But this just ignores all of the python files. How do I just watch the directories app and config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'm assuming you have [`watchfiles`](https://pypi.org/project/watchfiles/) installed)

### TL;DR

Use recurring Unix's filename pattern matching to exclude all '.py' the add the ones you need to be watched one by one:

```py
uvicorn.run(
    "app.main:fast",
    host=host,
    port=port,
    log_level=log_level,
    reload=reload,
    reload_includes=[
        "app/**/*.py",
        "config/**/*",
        "manage.py",
        ".env"
    ],
    reload_excludes=[
        "./**/*.py",
    ]
)
```

### Pattern matching

Firstly, if the directory named `private` have `.py` files, it'll be watched by default [see Uvicorn documentation](https://www.uvicorn.org/settings/#reloading-with-watchfiles). You need to give a list of [Unix's filename pattern matching](https://pymotw.com/2/glob/) to both `reload_excludes` and `reload_includes`. The patterns you are providing only matches directories and files in first level.

For instance, run:

```py
from pathlib import Path
current_dir = Path.cwd()
for match in current_dir.glob("app/*"):
    print(match)
```

and you'll see that it will output all directories and files inside "app" directory, but not it's sub-folders or files in them.

### Recursively targeting a files extension

For recurring file matching, say you want to target all html files inside the directory named 'templates'. Use the following filename pattern matching: `"templates/**/*.html"`.

Now say you also want to target all .js and .css files inside a 'staticfiles' directory.

```py
uvicorn.run(
    "app.main:fast",
    host=host,
    port=port,
    log_level=log_level,
    reload=reload,
    reload_includes=[
        "templates/**/*.html",
        "staticfiles/**/*.css",
        "staticfiles/**/*.js"
    ]
)
```

### Excluding `.py` files from inside a folder

Now say you also want you want to exclude all '.py' files inside 'private' directory. Even if you pass `"private/**/*.py"` to `reload_excludes` argument, since `**/*.py` is included by default you'll have to exclude patterns `**/*.py` and add all the other Python file pattern one by one:

```py
uvicorn.run(
    "app.main:fast",
    host=host,
    port=port,
    log_level=log_level,
    reload=reload,
    reload_includes=[
        "templates/**/*.html",
        "staticfiles/**/*.css",
        "staticfiles/**/*.js"
        "app/**/*.py",
        "config/**/*",
        "manage.py",
        ".env",
        reload_excludes=[
            "./**/*.py",
        ]
    ]
)
```

Comment: It's been awhile so idk if this'll work, but accepting this because I recognize that these are the correct glob strings!

Answer (score -1):

```py
uvicorn.run(
        "app.main:fast",
        host=host,
        port=port,
        log_level=log_level,
        reload=reload,
        reload_dirs=["app", "config"]
    )
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work.